# Mute All Sound From a WebBrowser Component?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

How can I do that, I basically want to mute all sound (Videos, Music) from my WebBrowser Component. Is there any way to do that? I only want it muted from the program's webbrowser component, not my computers volume.

Comment: Can't you mute sound for your process?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default TWebBrowser I'm afriad you won't be able to do this without muting the sound of your entire application. Reasons why I suspect it can't be done:

1. TWebBrowser component is actually just a wraper for Microsoft Internet Explorer interface which is accesilbe through COM object. Now it is posible to disable some sound in Internet Explorer through its settings but I don't know if TWebBrowser alows you to change those settings for your specific instance.
2. Some sounds on webpages (music, video) might not be even played by the browser itself but by certain plugins like Flash Player, Shockwave Player, etc. In most cases these don't get muted even when you change your Internet Explorer Settings to not play any media files.

Anywhay I'm afraid you will have pretty hard job in achieveing this without changing the windows sound settings.

Now if you target Windows Vista and newer you might be able to force partial mutting of your application by creating new interface of your application for rendering WebBrowser (similar as Internet Explorer does for each tab). This way you could change sound settigs for each of your applications interface seperately using system sound mixer.

Comment: To disable playing background sounds in `TWebBrowser` control, you can omit the `DLCTL_BGSOUNDS` flag from the returned value when the `DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL` property is queried (e.g. [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/avfgYeKV)). But as you say, that won't mute sounds played by plugins. More about that flag in [`this chapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28VS.85%29.aspx#Controlling_Download_and_Execution).